# When a function is called in Javascript, is there then an easy way to find where a function is declared in?

Tags: javascript

It would be great if some IDE offered the way to right mouse click when a function is called and have the immediate option to jump to the function when it is defined.

Is this possible in Javascript?

Maybe I've just been oblivious - is there a name for this technique?

Comment: The Resharper plugin for Visual Studio has this feature.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken this is possible in visual studio when you're debugging a website. It connects to the running IE and correlates the javascript being executed to the source code it served to IE.

Comment: Check out Webstorm. Written by the same guys who made IntelliJ and ReSharper. But yeah, JS is highly mutable so it's best guess without run-time unless something happens to be declared within the same function scope.

Answer (score 9):

This really is never going to be possible with JavaScript.  Some IDE's do a "best guess", but it will never be perfect.  Since JavaScript uses a dynamic type system, it is impossible to perform static analysis to determine what a symbol is bound to until runtime.

The closest thing to this would be in-browser debugging tools such as Firebug or chrome's developer tools, which do allow this feature at runtime.

Comment: Also Firebug allows the user to evaluate a function in the console and clicking on it takes you to the definition.